# Optimize Powershell script for Azure NSG

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-nsg

I have a script for finding all inbound, allow rules in Azure NSG which source is any. It is doing his job but it takes **just an enormous** amount of time to iterate every rule in every available NSG in Azure.

Question is there is any way to optimize it, so it could work faster? Thanks!

```
function nsg {

# List of default rules which are skipped

$array =
'Default rules'

# Get all RG with NSG

$RGS = (Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=resourcetype eq 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups'").ResourceGroupName | Sort-Object -Unique

foreach ($RG in $RGS) { 

# List of all NSG names

$NSG_Names = (Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $RG).Name

# Get NSG rules

foreach ($NSG_Name in $NSG_Names){

$Rules = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSG_Name -ResourceGroupName $RG | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Check if rule is not default

foreach ($Rule in $Rules){

    if ($array.contains($Rule)){

    Write-Verbose "$Rule excluded because it is default!"

    }
else {

    Write-Verbose "$NSG_Name - $Rule"

    #$DestinationAddressPrefix = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSG_Name -ResourceGroupName $RG | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $Rule | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DestinationAddressPrefix
    $DestinationPortRange = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSG_Name -ResourceGroupName $RG | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $Rule | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DestinationPortRange
    $SourceAddrPref = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSG_Name -ResourceGroupName $RG | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $Rule | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SourceAddressPrefix
    $SourcePortRange = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSG_Name -ResourceGroupName $RG | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $Rule | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SourcePortRange
    $Access = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSG_Name -ResourceGroupName $RG | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $Rule | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access
    $Direction = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSG_Name -ResourceGroupName $RG | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $Rule | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Direction

# Chek rule for every criterion, access type, etc.

    if ($Direction -eq "Inbound" -and $SourceAddrPref -eq "*" -and $Access -eq "Allow"){ #-and $DestinationAddressPrefix -eq "*" -and $DestinationPortRange -eq "*") {

       $message = "Warning! RG: $RG; NSG: $NSG_Name has SOURCE ANY Rule: $Rule to Destionation Port: $DestinationPortRange"
       $message

}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to iterate all that data. All those nested loops + sorting is whats causing the slowdown.

It seems to me that you just want to output all your NSGs with direction `Inbound` and access is `Allow` and source address prefix as `*`. If this is the case, you can do this:

```
$nsgs = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup

foreach ($nsg in $nsgs.SecurityRules)
{
    if ($nsg.Direction -eq "Inbound" -and $nsg.Access -eq "Allow" -and $nsg.SourceAddressPrefix -eq "*")
    {
        $nsg
    }
}
```

Here we just iterate the security rules you have made from `$nsgs.SecurityRules`.  The default ones are in `$nsgs.DefaultSecurityRules`. You can pipe to `Get-Member` to find these properties.